# How to make a:hover images scroll with div box

Tags: css, html, hover

alite so i used a tutorial from this site: http://www.webreference.com/programming/css_gallery/index.html

the problem is, when i added more images, the gallery on the right fell out of the div margins. to fix this i used overflow:auto. now when there are a lot more images, i am allowed to scroll down my div. problem is the image shown when i hover is positioned at the top part of the div. so when i scroll down too much, the image either gets cut out from the top or doesnt appear at all. so its kinda like on this page right here. if you scroll down this page far enough you wont see this post any more unless you scroll back up. is there a css code that i can use to fix this. basically what i want it a position:fixed effect in the div box with the hover thing. so how do i edit the tutorial code to do that?

Comment: Could you show what you're having atm.? Maybe create a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/? — The demo on the linked page breaks for me.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with step 9 in the tutorial

```
#container li { 
        float:left; 
 }
```

An important concept to know with floats is the **clear** property. Because the space of the images exceed that of the containing div, the images effectively fall out of the div. There are several ways to resolve this issue. Read here for more http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

1.`overflow: auto;` like you have already implemented

2.define a class

```
.clear {
      clear:both;
}
```

and put <div class="clear"> right before the closing tag of the container

3.Use pseudo selector **:after**

```
.clearfix:after { 
   content: "."; 
   visibility: hidden; 
   display: block; 
   height: 0; 
   clear: both;
}
```

change <div id="container"> ... to <div id="container" class="clearfix">

Personally, I prefer method 3, because it makes markup cleaner. Just be aware of browser compatibility for method 3.